# $G$ has a cyclic normal subgroup $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to prove the following result:

$\newcommand{\gal}{\operatorname{Gal}}$

Let $F\subset E$ be a Galois extension and assume that $E=F(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^n\in F$. Let $$G=\gal(E/F)$$.

> Prove that $G$ has a cyclic normal subgroup $H$ of order dividing $n$ such that $G/H$ is abelian and has order dividing $\phi(n)$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: @Acuo95, thanks for your edit!

Comment: Ahahah, you're welcome. So sorry that i didn't give you an answer :D

Comment: no problem,  Acuo95 thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I think lhf already gave an excellent hint. Anymore on that is to give you almost the whole answer:

So $\;E\;$ contains all the roots of unity of order $\;n\;$ . Whether some of these roots were already in $\;F\;$ or not, $\;E\;$ contains all the roots of an irreducible polynomial (over $\;F\;$) dividing $\;x^n-1\in F[x]\;$ . We know the set of automorphisms (over $\;F\;$) permuting these roots is a cyclic one.

Now use the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory to deduce that the field that fixes these roots must be normal and, of course, corresponds to a normal *cyclic* (since any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic) subgroup of $\;G\;$ .

Finally, just remember that the degree of the cyclotomic polynomial of order $\;n\;$ is $\;\phi(n)\;$, which also gives the order of the corresponding extension, and that taking into account that some of those roots of unity may already be in $\;F\;$ , we then must get *a divisor* of $\;\phi(n)\;$ as the order of the corresponding group (or of the corresponding subextension).

Comment: and if we suppose that $n$ is prime does that imply $G$ is itself cyclic?

Comment: @iskander No need to assume such a thing: the (multiplicative, of course) group of roots of unity *of any order* is always cyclic.

Comment: is it right for the example $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ ?

Comment: @iskander I don't understand you: that inclusion is trivial...

Comment: my question is the following: Show that if $n$  is prime then $ G$ itself  is cyclic, but that is not necessairely true if $n$ is composite (example $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{-3})$)

Comment: Well, no. For example, $\;F=\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)=E\;$ , with $\;\alpha=\sqrt[3]2\implies \alpha^3=2\in\Bbb Q=E\;$ . But here $\;G=Gal(E/F)\cong S_3\;$ , which is not even abelian. Anyway, what do you need this for? This is **not what you asked** ...

Comment: but $S_3$ is cyclic since 3 is prime if we take the example that i gave with 6 is comprime how to prove that $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: @iskander If you don't know $\;S_3\;$ is **not** cyclic (as commented: not even abelian!), then I think you should go back to the very, very basics before even attempt to cope with these questions. In my university, you **must first** past a course in basic group theory and rings, **and then after that** you get into fields extension and Galois Theory.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $E$ contains all $n$-th roots of unity because $E/F$ is Galois and $\alpha^n\in F$. Note that some of these roots may already be in $F$.

Comment: exactly that is what i was thinking to use, but i don't know how?

Comment: the set $H$ is it the set of all the $n$-th roots?

Comment: @iskander, $H$ is in $G$, not in $E$.

Comment: you are right, I don't see crearly the answer

Comment: @iskander You don't know... **what**? The polynomial $\;x^n-\alpha^n\in F[x]\;$ has a root ($\;\alpha\;$) in $\;E\;$ , and thus **all** its roots are there as the extension is Galois. The roots of that polynomial are $\;\alpha\zeta^k\;,\;\;k=0,1,...,n\;,\;\;\zeta\;$ a primitive $\;n\,-$th root of unity...Now continue with the hint by lhf .

Comment: @ DonAntonio, sorry for my dump answer!

Comment: i don't know how to continue i think that i will unfotunatly fall in this subject

Comment: Can you please help me more? thanks in advance